# Looking for UK and Republic of Ireland combined GEO JSON file

Tags: json, map

Does anyone know how I can find a UK and Republic of Ireland combined GEO JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you may not be able to find such a GEOJSON file. Your best option might be to download the respective GEOJSON files of the UK and Ireland and then combine them. You can find the files here https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/